# Matlab: multiply a cell by a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I currently do this:

```
x1 = {...}; %a 1xn cell with each element being a column vector
w = [...]; %some column vector
result = zeros(n,1);

% now I want to multiply each vector in x by w

for i = 1:n
  result(i) = w'*cell2mat(x1(i));
end
```

This works of course but the idea behind Matlab is to make use of it's optimised vector and matrix multiplication etc. So I though I'm probably doing something wrong. Is there a better way of doing the above performance-wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can replace your `for` loop with just:

```
result = w'*cell2mat(x1);
```

Comment: If so, please could you accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark underneath the voting arrows?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use

```
result = cellfun(@(x) w'*x,x1);
```

Though I think the other answer will be quicker.